# How to limit the request per second in my play framework project

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, threadpool

I have a 5M records in mysql, and my task is:

for each record, transform it to a json object and insert it to mongodb.

my issue is that while transforming it to a json, before i insert the object to mongo I need to call some google api, and google have 50 requests per second (QPS) limit.

How should I make sure I dont exceed this limit and still have the fastest possible execution?

to test out the api in the function that perform the call to google api i'v put Thread.sleep(200) (i know its bad, just for testing purposes), but now I need to run it on 5M records so I need to performance to be as fast as possible

sorry if the answer is too obvious I might dont understand something fundamental, maybe its because im a newbie :\
thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play WS API: throttling request rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259206/play-ws-api-throttling-request-rates)

Comment: Which version of play do you use? Do you use slick for accessing mysql?

Comment: @ValeriiRusakov I use quill. and play version is 2.6.11

Comment: @jackmiao I have solution for play 2.6 based on streams but unfortunately quill doesn't support them :(